# Accessing Videos in library using AssetsLibrary framework iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios4, alassetslibrary

I am trying to access videos in iPhone library using AssetsLibrary Framework with the help of following code...but when I run the application the code is not working...the array assets is still empty? What am I doing wrong?

by the way my iPhone is a 3G upgraded to iPhone 4.1.(but assets framework is not giving any error)

```
NSMutableArray *assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];

void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if(result != NULL) {
                NSLog(@"See Asset: %@", result);
                [assets addObject:result];
            }
        };

    void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if(group != nil) {NSLog(@"dont See Asset: ");
                [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
            }
        };

    assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                           usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                         failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                                 NSLog(@"Failure");
                             }];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the 4.1 upgrade seems to have 'broken' some of the image picker examples, observe the following lines, which run after the code you have posted:

```
NSUInteger groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupAlbum | ALAssetsGroupEvent | ALAssetsGroupFaces;
[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:groupTypes usingBlock:listGroupBlock failureBlock:failureBlock];
```

This gives zero assets both on my 4.1 iPhone and simulator. However changing the groupTypes helps, so set

```
 NSUInteger groupTypes = ALAssetsGroupAll;
```

and you should start seeing some assets.

Answer (score 2):

I did this in Xcode 4.1, IOS 5:

```
ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock assetEnumerator = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if(result != NULL) {
        NSLog(@"See Asset: %@", result);
        [assets addObject:result];
    }
};

ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock assetGroupEnumerator = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if(group != nil) {NSLog(@"dont See Asset: ");
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
    }
};

assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                     failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                         NSLog(@"Failure");
                     }];
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Double Init:

```
 NSMutableArray *assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 ALAssetsLibrary *library =[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];

 void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
 if(result != NULL) {
      NSLog(@"See Asset: %@", result);
      [assets addObject:result];

        }
};

void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if(group != nil) {NSLog(@"dont See Asset: ");
            [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
    }
};

   assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init**];
   [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                     failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                             NSLog(@"Failure");
                         }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using ELC Image Picker Controller, and it's already using ALAssetsGroupAll and still not showing any videos.

I **solved** this by adding an asset filter. You can limit to videos, photos or both. I guess photos-only was the default. Please consider the following line if the above fails:

```
[assetGroup setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allAssets]];
```