# How to select a video file and upload to server in iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, video

I want to select an video file located in my iPhone and have to upload it to the server.

As UIImagePicker is used to select pictures available in our photo library or some other mode, is any option to select a file located in our iPhone programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Assets library. Refer this question: [Accessing Videos in library using AssetsLibrary framework iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948485/accessing-videos-in-library-using-assetslibrary-framework-iphone)

And on searching, I found [this method](http://sol3.typepad.com/tagalong_developer_journa/2009/07/recorded-video-from-iphone-3gs-.html) to access videos using image picker controller.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply,is Assests library the only option for it?

Comment: @Priya: Upto my knowledge its the only thing. I cant surely tell that there is no other thing.

Comment: I have added assertLibrary framework and included the code for it, but it not recognizing, which header files are to be included? if any samples or tutorial please send me samples

Answer (score 0):

First Add the `MediaPlayer` Framework...

Then download video of type mp4 from mobile9.com

then use the code as follows

```
NSString *url=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"video" ofType:@"mp4"];

MPMoviePlayerController *play1= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL 
fileURLwithPath:url];

[play1 setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];

[paly1 play];
```

try this code .....it's working..

Answer (score 0):

```
to select video from photo library use following code:
 UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```